# PySide emit signal causes python to crash

Tags: python, signals-slots, pyside

I am working through the book "Rapid Gui Programming with Python and Qt" and am having a problem on the signals/slots project.  I have downloaded the authors code to compare against my own, and it all looks the same, however, when I emit a signal from a derived spin box class, python just crashes.  Here is the entire code that I have:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class ZeroSpinBox(QSpinBox):
    zeros = 0

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ZeroSpinBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"), self.checkzero)

    def checkzero(self):
        if self.value() == 0:
            self.zeros += 1
            self.emit(SIGNAL("atzero"), self.zeros)

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        dial = QDial()
        dial.setNotchesVisible(True)
        spinbox = ZeroSpinBox()
        spinbox.setRange(0,200)
        dial.setRange(0,200)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(dial)
        layout.addWidget(spinbox)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.connect(dial, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"), spinbox, SLOT("setValue(int)"))
        self.connect(spinbox, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"), dial, SLOT("setValue(int)"))
        self.connect(spinbox, SIGNAL("atzero"), self.announce)

        self.setWindowTitle("Signals and Slots Part 2")

    def announce(self, zeros):
        print "ZeroSpinBox has been at zero %d times" % zeros


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

My problem occurs when the spinbox goes down to zero, the checkzero(self) method (of the ZeroSpinBox class) gets called, the self.zeros += 1 line is ok, then on the emit line windows reports that Python.exe has crashed.  The error I get is "python.exe has stopped working" and the console reports "Process finished with exit code -1073741819"

Any idea why this is happening?  This is Python 2.7.2 and PyQT4 w/PySide.

Comment: Tried another program that does an emit, and same thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute `SIGNAL("atzero")` with `SIGNAL("atzero(int)")` both in `checkzero` and in `Form.__init__`, because the way you're declaring it, it carries no argument.

Edit: your code in the "new-style",

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class ZeroSpinBox(QSpinBox):
    zeros = 0

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ZeroSpinBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.valueChanged.connect(self.checkzero)

    atzero = Signal(int)

    def checkzero(self):
        if self.value() == 0:
            self.zeros += 1
            self.atzero.emit(self.zeros)

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        dial = QDial()
        dial.setNotchesVisible(True)
        spinbox = ZeroSpinBox()
        spinbox.setRange(0,200)
        dial.setRange(0,200)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(dial)
        layout.addWidget(spinbox)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        dial.valueChanged.connect(spinbox.setValue)
        spinbox.valueChanged.connect(dial.setValue)
        spinbox.atzero.connect(self.announce)

        self.setWindowTitle("Signals and Slots Part 2")

    @Slot(int)
    def announce(self, zeros):
        print "ZeroSpinBox has been at zero %d times" % zeros


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  However, the book is specifically saying not to put any parenthesis, says it creates a "short-circuit" signal.  I'll research further into that, appreciate your answer.

Comment: Guess the "short-circuit" signals is a PyQT feature that wasn't brought over for PySide.  For future readers, this vaguely touches on it, but explains it enough for me to know it's not happening with PySide - http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Differences_Between_PySide_and_PyQt#5fa7b08138cabe061590146f6da8a2a0

Comment: No idea in that sense. I was also trying to translate your code to new-style Slot/Signal syntax in PyQt/PySide, but for some reason it's translating them wrong. Could be my old version...

Comment: @Mike: I've added a version of your code that uses the new style Slot/Signal syntax. It didn't work right away before because I was using PySide 0.4, but in this other computer I've got 1.1 and works as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo.  It helps to see the new style in action alongside the old way.  Appreciate you taking the time to write that up.

Answer (score 2):

This due to a difference between PySide and PyQt4, which is documented [here](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Differences_Between_PySide_and_PyQt#5fa7b08138cabe061590146f6da8a2a0) (actually, strictly speaking, this is a bug in PySide - using a unsupported form of signal syntax should produce an error, not crash the application).

The book you are using was written specifically for PyQt4, and so you probably need to be aware of the differences between PySide and PyQt4 when using it. See [here](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html#pyside), for example.

Note that the PyQt4 version of your script works fine, with or without the parenthesized portion of the signal - all that matters is that they are the same. However, this is only true for *user-defined* signals - for predefined Qt signals and slots, you must always include the parenthesized portion of the signature.

Another thing you should be aware of, is that the signal/slot syntax you are using has been superceeded by a much more pythonic new-style syntax. So, at some point, it would be worthwhile reading through the guidance found [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), if your book doesn't cover it.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew the book was for PyQt4, but being new to it didn't know much about the differences between that and PySide.  I'll look into the new signal/slot syntax, appreciate the pointer.